# Calling prepareStatement first time works fine but second time getting java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed

Tags: java, oracle11g, weblogic

I have a requirement to process couple of records, for this Recently i installed Oracle 11g data base and using that data base to connect my application and i run the batch job to process those records by using while loop every time i checked for records exists or not if exits loop continue. When i run the batch job first record getting using `m_dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);` first time it will fetch the record and process complete and second time it goes to check the record we call same statement `m_dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);` when i call this second time i got `java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.`

**This is my code to get connection:**

> ```
> public static Connection getPoolConnection() throws SQLException{
>     String dataSourceJNDI;
>     Connection lConnection = null;    
>     dataSourceJNDI = ApplnProperty.getInstance().getProperty("CONPOOL");
>     try{
>        if (mlPoolStore.get(dataSourceJNDI) != null) {
>
>         return ((DataSource) mlPoolStore.get(sourceJNDI)).getConnection();
>        }
>
>        InitialContext lInitCtx = null;
>        lInitCtx = new InitialContext();
>        DataSource lDs = (DataSource)lInitCtx.lookup(sourceJNDI);
>        mlPoolStore.put(dataSourceJNDI, lDs);
>        lConnection = lDs.getConnection();
>       return lConnection; 
>      } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>             throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
>         }
>     }
> ```

This method calling to get record:

> ```
> public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String query) throws SQLException
>    {
>       if (isConnectionClosed) throw new SQLException("Connection is Closed");
>       PreparedStatement ps = m_dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
>       m_stmtList.add(ps);
>       return ps;
>    }
> ```

connection is alive but calling this

`PreparedStatement ps = m_dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);`

statement getting exception

**Please find the complete exception below:**

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
>         at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.checkConnection(PoolConnection.java:55)
>         at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.preInvocationHandler(Connection.java:92)
>         at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:482)
>         at com.orbitreasury.infrastructure.DBConnection.getPreparedStatement(DBConnection.java:464)
>         at com.orbitreasury.moneymarket.businessimplementation.entity.RepriceEntity.getRepriceDeals(RepriceEntity.java:126)
>         at com.orbitreasury.moneymarket.businessimplementation.RepriceDeals.updateRepriceDeals(RepriceDeals.java:896)
>         at com.orbitreasury.moneymarket.eventhandler.RepriceJobEvent.processEvent(RepriceJobEvent.java:91)
>         at com.orbitreasury.common.control.NavigationController.processEvent(NavigationController.java:232)
>         at com.orbitreasury.common.control.NavigationController.onEvent(NavigationController.java:121)
>         at WebRequestController.processLocalRequest(WebRequestController.java:348)
>         at WebRequestController.doPost(WebRequestController.java:138)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3495)
>         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>         at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
>         at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>         at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
> java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
>         at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.checkConnection(PoolConnection.java:55)
>         at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.preInvocationHandler(Connection.java:92)
>         at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:482)
>         at com.orbitreasury.infrastructure.DBConnection.getPreparedStatement(DBConnection.java:464)
>         at com.orbitreasury.moneymarket.businessimplementation.entity.RepriceEntity.getRepriceDeals(RepriceEntity.java:126)
>         at com.orbitreasury.moneymarket.businessimplementation.RepriceDeals.updateRepriceDeals(RepriceDeals.java:896)
>         at com.orbitreasury.moneymarket.eventhandler.RepriceJobEvent.processEvent(RepriceJobEvent.java:91)
>         at com.orbitreasury.common.control.NavigationController.processEvent(NavigationController.java:232)
>         at com.orbitreasury.common.control.NavigationController.onEvent(NavigationController.java:121)
>         at WebRequestController.processLocalRequest(WebRequestController.java:348)
>         at WebRequestController.doPost(WebRequestController.java:138)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3495)
>         at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>         at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
>         at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
>         at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>         at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
> ```

**My weblogic connection pool configuration:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show how you get connection to DB.

Comment: This is OK. I mean show your code where you obtain a connection to DB.

Comment: sorry, it's a huge code to show you.

Comment: We don't need the whole application. Just the part where you get the connection to DB. I would expect these are just a couple of lines o code.

Comment: Same scenario works in another environment, but it is not worked since latest installation of oracle 11g database onwards.

Comment: The connection. Is *not* alive. The error message says so. In general it is a mistake to have a connection as a member variable. It should be obtained within the method that needs it as a local variable and closed in the same method. Connection pooling will mitigate the overhead. And don't write your own.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have retrieved `m_dbConnection` once and keep it as a member variable in your class `com.orbitreasury.infrastructure.DBConnection`. Instead, retrieve connection *each time* you need it. You should not try to optimize the work of connection pool. It is pretty complex task. Connection pool already does it for you. Instead of

```
m_dbConnection.prepareStatement(templateSql)
```

use

```
getPoolConnection().prepareStatement(templateSql)
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't add your code, so it's hard to know what is the issue.

I can guess you added some "finally" block, and closed your connection - ***m_dbConnection***.

So you can't use it anymore.
Try to close only after you finish to touch DB.

Comment: :< why downgrading without a reason :(